How can I fetch football leagues by date using the football API?
I am trying to use the football API to fetch a list of football leagues based on a specific date. I want to display this information in my Next.js application, but I am not sure how to properly make the API call.
I have tried using the provided endpoint 'https://football.sportdevs.com/leagues-by-date?date=eq.{date}' with the desired date parameter, but I am not getting the expected data back. I expected to receive a list of football leagues for the specified date.
const date = '2022-01-01';
fetch(`https://football.sportdevs.com/leagues-by-date?date=eq.${date}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));


Give the exact working link where you want to fetch data

You are missing an API key; without an API key, you can't test api results
For this, you should follow these steps:

Go to this URL: https://sportdevs.com/pricing
choose your sports and subscribe to a paid or free option
Sign up with email or gmail account
get api key from dashboard

If you test the API key with code, it will work perfectly
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer your_api_key");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://football.sportdevs.com/leagues-by-date?date=eq.2022-01-01", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));


